# MySQL - removing ID columns used for joining

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables of data I'm joining together. I'm using an ID column (day) in each table to join the data together. The following SQL query works, and provides the following column set:

```
SELECT * 
FROM records 
LEFT JOIN macro_nutrients ON macro_nutrients.day = records.day 
LEFT JOIN micro_nutrients ON micro_nutrients.day = records.day

day|date|calories_in|calories_out|day|fat|sugar|protein|day|iron|cholesterol|potassium|vitamin_a|vitamin_c|
```

As I join tables, the "day" field (which works as my primary key for joining tables) gets outputted each time (3 tables would have three day fields listed). I would like to exclude the day fields from my column set, as they aren't needed.

Would this only be achievable by explicitly mentioning the fields I want in my select statement (eg. macro_nutrients.fat)? this would unfortunately get quite verbose if so. Curious if there a more compact way.

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` if you want more control over which columns to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `USING`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM records r LEFT JOIN
     macro_nutrients man
     USING (day) LEFT JOIN
     micro_nutrients mn
     USING (day);
```

`USING` is SQL standard syntax that both SQLite and MySQL support.  When `*` is used with `USING`, the columns used as `JOIN` keys are not duplicated in the result set.  In an outer join, the value is the actual value in the data -- rather than the unmatched `NULL` value.

Comment: The "using" command worked perfectly. The datasets joined as expected, without the id's being duplicated in the result set.